# Need help with understanding the pros and cons of geometric and stochastic based channel models. Which one s preferred under which conditions?

Tags: wireless, 802.11

https://www.adv-radio-sci.net/9/165/2011/ars-9-165-2011.pdf

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7794648

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c301/8463116117ea64f69638e15aa78fe9e84093.pdf

https://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9783642174957-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1113975-p174079771

The above links are papers that describe the different channel models. My question specifically is that are there any scenarios where using one is advantageous than the other one. I read that it is preferred to use geometry based models as it can distinguish between LOS and NLOS in vehicular network scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

There are pro's and cons of predictable and unpredictable noise models.  Each can respectively give an estimate of packet loss with tolerances or a probability curve. But there are always exceptions from Doppler velocity and Rician Fading due to reflections or NLoS paths.

A sensor-based Doppler-shift prediction and compensation approach outperforms a benchmark least-squares channel estimation with linear interpolation algorithm.

Due to NLOS, multiple copies of signals arrive at different times with different amplitudes. This results in ISI/ICI. This problem is avoided with the use of OFDM and OFDMA techniques along with cyclic prefix. **The cyclic prefix length is kept greater than delay spread value to overcome ISI/ICI.** [REF](http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/ISI-vs-ICI.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I understand what you are trying to say. I will look for more on the exact differences and benefits of the two propagation models. Will post here if I have any more questions.

Comment: The differences in analysis involve doppler conditions as the results are very dynamic. I added best guess on solutions to minimize these problems when performing analysis on PER (packet error rate)